# Java : Cannot format given Object as a Date

Tags: java

I have Date in this format  (2012-11-17T00:00:00.000-05:00). I need to convert the date into this format mm/yyyy.

I tried this way, but I am getting this Exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)
    at DateParser.main(DateParser.java:14)
```

Please see my code below:

```java
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateParser {    
  public static void main(String args[]) {   
    String MonthYear = null;    
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/yyyy");    
    String dateformat = "2012-11-17T00:00:00.000-05:00";
    MonthYear = simpleDateFormat.format(dateformat);    
    System.out.println(MonthYear);    
  }    
}
```

Comment: The `SimpleDateFormat#format` require a `Date` instance, not `String`.
So you should convert the string to `Date` by `SimpleDateFormat#parse` first.

Comment: 2019 comment: You shouldn’t use `SimpleDateFormat` at all anymore. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`DateFormat.format` only works on `Date` values.

You should use two SimpleDateFormat objects: one for parsing, and one for formatting. For example:

```
// Note, MM is months, not mm
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", Locale.US);

String inputText = "2012-11-17T00:00:00.000-05:00";
Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputText);
String outputText = outputFormat.format(date);
```

EDIT: Note that you may well want to specify the time zone and/or locale in your formats, and you should *also* consider using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of all of this to start with - it's a much better date/time API.

Comment: Your answer looks good than mine , i have one  more question , how can i get only the  Date  (2012-11-17T00:00:00.000-05:00) that is 17 from this ??

Comment: @yyyi777: As a string, or as an integer value?

Comment: @yyyi777: Use a SimpleDateFormat of "dd" or possibly just "d", depending on whether you want zero-padding.

Answer (score 14):

### java.time

I should like to contribute the modern answer. The `SimpleDateFormat` class is notoriously troublesome, and while it was reasonable to fight one’s way through with it when this question was asked six and a half years ago, today we have much better in java.time, the modern Java date and time API. `SimpleDateFormat` and its friend `Date` are now considered long outdated, so don’t use them anymore.

```
    DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/uuuu");
    String dateformat = "2012-11-17T00:00:00.000-05:00";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateformat);
    String monthYear = dateTime.format(monthFormatter);
    System.out.println(monthYear);
```

Output:

> 11/2012

I am exploiting the fact that your string is in ISO 8601 format, the international standard, and that the classes of java.time parse this format as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter. It’s stil true what the other answers say, you need to parse the original string first, then format the resulting date-time object into a new string. Usually this requires two formatters, only in this case we’re lucky and can do with just one formatter.

### What went wrong in your code

- As others have said, `SimpleDateFormat.format` cannot accept a `String` argument, also when the parameter type is declared to be `Object`.
- Because of the exception you didn’t get around to discovering: there is also a bug in your format pattern string, `mm/yyyy`. Lowercase `mm` os for minute of the hour. You need uppercase `MM` for month.
- Finally the Java naming conventions say to use a lowercase first letter in variable names, so use lowercase `m` in `monthYear` (also because java.time includes a `YearMonth` class with uppercase `Y` and `M`, so to avoid confusion).

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 5):

You have one `DateFormat`, but you need two: one for the input, and another for the output.

You've got one for the output, but I don't see anything that would match your input.  When you give the input string to the output format, it's no surprise that you see that exception.

```
DateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddhh:mm:ss.SSS-Z");
```

Answer (score 4):

`SimpleDateFormat.format(...)` takes a Date as parameter and format Date to String. So you need have a look API carefully

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved it , this way

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DateParser {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        DateParser dateParser = new DateParser();

        String str = dateParser.getparsedDate("2012-11-17T00:00:00.000-05:00");
        System.out.println(str);
    }


    private String getparsedDate(String date) throws Exception {
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
        String s1 = date;
        String s2 = null;
        Date d;
        try {
            d = sdf.parse(s1);
            s2 = (new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy")).format(d);

        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return s2;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String showDate(){
    SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("\nTime：yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
    String s=df.format(new Date());
    return s;
}
```

I think this code may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
String dat="02/08/2017";
long date=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dat,newParsePosition(0)).getTime();
java.sql.Date dbDate=new java.sql.Date(date);
System.out.println(dbDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do it ninja style

```
String input = "2012-11-17T00:00:00.000-05:00";
String year = input.substring(0,4);
String month = input.substring(5,7);

String formattedDate = month + "/" + year;
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```