# Java Localize DateFormat Cannot format given Object as a Date

Tags: java, localization

I wish to get a localized date string. For that, I'm doing:

```
String dateString = "2019-06-01 00:15:00";
dateString = dateString.replace(" ", "T");
dateString = dateString.concat("Z");

DateFormat dateformat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.FRENCH);
System.out.println(dateformat.format(dateString));
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a
>   Date

What could be wrong here?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V. Can you provide a sample for localization using DateTimeFormatter?

Comment: Isn't DateFormat.format suppose to format a date object to a string? Not the other way around?

Comment: Are you... trying to format string as a string?

Comment: @OleV.V. If you could make your comment an answer, I can mark it as answer

Comment: @M.Prokhorov yes

Comment: @user5155835, date formatter can't do that. You will have to parse date from your string first, then format the date.

Comment: @user5155835 I have only hesitatingly done that. I still tend to consider this question a duplicate, so you may find better answers by searching for questions like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time

```
    String dateString = "2019-06-01 00:15:00";
    dateString = dateString.replace(" ", "T");
    dateString = dateString.concat("Z");

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT, FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
            .withLocale(Locale.FRENCH);
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-06-01T00:15:00Z");
    String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(formatter);

    System.out.println("Formatted date/time: " + formattedDateTime);
```

Output:

> Formatted date/time: 01/06/2019 00:15:00

I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, as shown in my code.

For what went wrong in your code please see the similar question that I link to at the bottom.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- Similar question: [Java : Cannot format given Object as a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649782/java-cannot-format-given-object-as-a-date). [My answer to the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52405866/5772882).