# Jackson - LocalDateTime format

Tags: java-8, jackson, datetime-format, iso8601

I know there are several questions of the same topic but I don't think they quite cover my problem in a Spring Boot 2 application.

I have a model which uses LocalTimeDate. Getting this via rest api works fine, date is of the format "date":"2019-12-17T08:50:00"

I have created Serializer so that the json output is customised as there are reference fields that I do not want expanded.

The relevant code in the custom serialzer is

```
jgen.writeStringField("date", formatter.format(value.date));
```

with formatter as

```
private SimpleDateFormat formatter  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

I apply @JsonSerialize using the custom serialzer class to the model class. The result  is

> {"timestamp":"2019-12-25T10:57:50.482+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal
>   Server Error","message":"Could not write JSON: Cannot format given
>   Object as a Date; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot format
>   given Object as a Date (through reference chain:
>   java.util.ArrayList[0])","path":"/api/v1/climates"}

I have used https://codeboje.de/jackson-java-8-datetime-handling/ as a guide and so updated the pom and application.properties and then allowed Spring to do its magic.

Is there something I have missed?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is an obsolete class, used to parse and format the obsolete java.util.Date class. Read the LocalDateTime javadoc to learn how to format a LocalDateTime. But simply using toString() will give you the standard, ISO format.

Comment: I seriously doubt that you need any custom serializer. I solved a similar problem by using [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) and setting `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` to false. (And I agree that you should under all circumstances stay away from `SimpleDateFormat`.)

Comment: Related: [Java : Cannot format given Object as a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649782/java-cannot-format-given-object-as-a-date)

Comment: Also, note that your "2019-12-25T10:57:50.482+0000" contains time-zone info which your format doesn't handle, also LocalDateTime does not relate to timezone. This may be a problem. Also, like others I strongly agree - DO NOT TOUCH SimpleDateFormat. See java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually I went with

```
jgen.writeStringField("date", value.getDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
```

which worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`. In your case:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

and you can use it in the same way as obsoleted `SimpleDateFormat` class.