# Converting PST time to GMT

Tags: java, timezone

I am trying to convert a pst time stamp to gmt in java

I have a string with the time stamp of `2021-03-23T22:00:00.669-07:00`. How would I go about that string and convert to a gmt timestamp?

> ```
> 2021-03-24T05:03:00.669Z
> ```

I did something I attempted, but haven't gone everywhere

```
//Date date = new Date(str);
      
String s = str;
DateFormat pstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
TimeZone gmtTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
TimeZone pstTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST");
      
pstFormat.setTimeZone(gmtTime);
gmtFormat.setTimeZone(pstTime);
System.out.println("GMT Time: " + pstFormat.format(s));
System.out.println("PST Time: " + gmtFormat.format(s));
```

The result is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date` in this line:

```
System.out.println("GMT Time: " + pstFormat.format(s));
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use for example `OffsetDateTime` and `ZoneId`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java : Cannot format given Object as a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649782/java-cannot-format-given-object-as-a-date). Tip: paste your error messages into your search engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime
.parse( "2021-03-23T22:00:00.669-07:00" ) 
.toInstant()
.toString()
```

## Details

Never use those terrible date-time classes `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, and `TimeZone`. Supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Your input carries an offset-from-UTC of negative seven hours. So parse as an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2021-03-23T22:00:00.669-07:00" ) ;
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

Both your input and desired output comply with the ISO 8601 standard. The *java.time* classes use those standard formats by default when parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

Never use 2-4 letter pseudo-zones such as PST. Use [real time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in format of `Continent/Region` such as `America/Los_Angeles`. Furthermore, contrary to your first sentence, your input does *not* represent a moment in a specific time zone. Many time zones may share an offset of -07:00 at that moment, so no way to know which time zone was intended by your data source.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66768162/10819573) is well-explained and spot-on. Just in case, you need to convert such a date-time string to a date-time object in any timezone, you can use [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant(java.time.ZoneId)). You have a similar method, [`OffsetDateTime#withOffsetSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#withOffsetSameInstant(java.time.ZoneOffset)) to deal with `OffsetDateTime`.

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(getDateTimeInDifferentTimezone("2021-03-23T22:00:00.669-07:00", "Etc/UTC"));// GMT
        System.out.println(getDateTimeInDifferentTimezone("2021-03-23T22:00:00.669-07:00", "America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(getDateTimeInDifferentTimezone("2021-03-23T22:00:00.669-07:00", "Asia/Calcutta"));
    }

    static ZonedDateTime getDateTimeInDifferentTimezone(String txtDateTime, String timezone) {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(txtDateTime).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(timezone));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-24T05:00:00.669Z[Etc/UTC]
2021-03-24T01:00:00.669-04:00[America/New_York]
2021-03-24T10:30:00.669+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Note that the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>